# Extract the highest value from a json array using a shell script

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

Using jq, I extracted a json array from a data source that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "rank": 69,
    "name": "Luigi"
  },
  {
    "rank": 420,
    "name": "Peach"
  },
  {
    "rank": 666,
    "name": "Toad"
  },
  {
    "rank": 42,
    "name": "Mario"
  }
]
```

Is there an elegant way of extracting the highest value of a field in the array within a shell script? In this example, I'm trying to get "666". I could write a dedicated program to do this easily, but I'd prefer to stay in a single shell script, unless it's too ugly to do that. I'm in the context of an Ubuntu Docker container and can install additional packages if needed.

Comment: `grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' file.json | sort -n | tail -n1`

Comment: This works, but only if there are no other numeric values in the array. So it would work with my example but not the real data and the other answers are prettier. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can use `max_by` function:

`max_by(.rank)` will yield:

```
{
  "rank": 666,
  "name": "Toad"
}
```

The result can be then piped to extract `rank` from it: `max_by(.rank)|.rank` (gives `666`). Run this query from terminal by prepending it with `jq` – `jq 'max_by(.rank)|.rank'`.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Very clean, I should've read more about jq, didn't know these functions existed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. ;) ... now you have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the json is in a file called data.json :

```
cat data.json | jq .[].rank | sort -n -r | head -n 1
```

Comment: No need for the `cat`  really.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the other answer is more elegant.